# add conditional to array formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, conditional-statements

Have the following table.

```
       A        B         C          D                           
   1          DATASET 1         DATASET 2
   2  TRUE    "trial 1"  TRUE   "mouse 1"
   3  FALSE   "trial 2"  FALSE  "mouse 2"
   4  FALSE   "trial 3"  TRUE   "mouse 3"
```

In column A and column C, Google Sheet, have added a checkbox for each value (Google Sheet => Insert => checkbox). When i check the box value becomes TRUE.

Need to Add COLUMN E with combination of data like: B2 + D2 ("trial 1 mouse 1") ... etc..

was told to use following formula (it works flawlessly BUT doesn't take into consideration the CHECKBOXES so it adds all and every values from Column ):

```
    =ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(
    Array_constrain(B2:B;COUNTA(B2:B);1) & 
    TRANSPOSE(Array_constrain(B2:D;COUNTA(D2:D);1)));"""""";" "))
```

Question is simple:

**How to add, to ArrayFormula, a conditional to combine cells if both cells (you want to combine) are checked (= are TRUE)?**

the resulting table, given the conditional, should look like this below:

```
       A        B         C          D         E                         
   1          DATASET 1         DATASET 2    COMBINATIONS
   2  TRUE    "trial 1"  TRUE   "mouse 1"    "trial 1 mouse 1"
   3  FALSE   "trial 2"  FALSE  "mouse 2"    "trial 1 mouse 3"
   4  FALSE   "trial 3"  TRUE   "mouse 3"
```

As you can see, COLUMN E has combined JUST the values (from column B) checked (=TRUE) to the values in column D checked (=TRUE)

in the google sheet, line 35, you can see the checkboxes i mean:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XToxuw_86wxZoJuoxF-D5OYrjsXnReAqGBRtljqQ69k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A*C3:C; B3:B&" "&D3:D; ))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A3:A*C3:C; B3:B&D3:D; ); """"""; " "))
```

[image]

or if you just want to list it:

```
=FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(B3:B&D3:D; """"""; " "); A3:A*C3:C=1)
```

[image]